# Python - SQLITE3 Converting gps.log into gps.csv (NO GUI)

Tags: python, sqlite, csv, gps, raspberry-pi3

Im relatively new to python and Sqlite3, in a nutshell i'm trying to import data from my gps.log into a sqlite database.

Here's the breakdown of what i've been doing; following this guide: 
http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-import-csv/

so first i'm trying to import /........./gps.log 
it works and says Usage:import FILE TABLE 
then: .mode csv
and import /....../gps.csv gps
and says: empty file ??? 
then i do .fullschema and I get 'NO STAT tables available

does anyone have any recommendations on easier of better ways of achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but it sounds like you're trying to do it all via SQL commands? That's probably possible, but there are easier ways. I'd look into [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/). The pandas DataFrames have "read_csv" and "to_sql" methods that could make this process very easy.

Comment: Hi Superstew, Yeah im trying to do it all through SQLite3, i;m trying to  specify the log output to be pure CSV or purely comma delimited

Comment: So you aren't using python at all?

Comment: oh yeah python is being used as well

Comment: Ok, so is the input file (gps log) is in csv format? And you're trying to get that into a sqlite db?